# Maven Jacoco - multi module project. What is the easiest (centralized?) setup?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

For a Maven multi module project I can report Code coverage via the Jacoco Maven plugin. I know 2 working approaches for that. The first approach I describe below. The second approach is to append all jacoco results of the Maven modules in 1 jacoco.exec file in the project root.

In both approaches, I have to add a Jacoco plugin to each module's pom.xml. Also I have to add a few lines to the unit and/or integration test plugins. I know that I can use a parent-pom to shorten the code a bit.

**Question**: do I really need to add the jacoco plugin (and modified surefire/failsave plugins) to each module's pom.xml file? 
Is it possible to define in the project folder the jacoco plugin only once in the project root?

OK, to elaborate on approach 1, this is what I use.

1. Sonar project properties file in the project root.

```
sonar.projectKey=projectKey

sonar.sources=all source files
 
sonar.exclusions=someFolders 

sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=module1/target/jacoco.exec,module2/target/jacoco.exsonar.projectName=projectName

sonar.java.binaries=*/target/classes
```

The essential part of Maven is:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
         <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin-version}</version>
         <configuration>
            <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>jacoco-init</id>
               <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
               <id>jacoco-site</id>
               <phase>verify</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
             <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/integration/**/*.java</exclude> 
                  <exclude>**/*$*.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
           <configuration>
              <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
              <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
             ...
           </executions>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
```

Comment: in my opinion jacoco plugin should appear only in the parent pom,  what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Maxence Lecointe, you can just add all plugins to the parent pom. Put the plugins in the <dependencies> section and NOT in the <dependenciesManagement> section.

After scanning many solutions I created a simple but complete **Jacoco** demo project showing:

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- Jacoco - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

Enjoy the [sipmle demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).

Comment: your project has some dependencies problems. If you clean your local m2 repository and mvn install it, you'll see that two dependencies are missing. your module 1 has bad groupId declaration in module 3.

Comment: I have a sonar instance on my localhost and when I executed this command on your project, I didn't have coverage (0.0%)
Have you tried to deploy the coverage on a local (or a distant) sonarqube ?

`mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Psonar,test-all`

Comment: Quite long ago I had a local Sonar (docker?) instance and got it fixed. I had similar issues also at my work, but forgot how to fix them.

Comment: No, not docker. Just an instance on Windows.

Comment: In the maven log you will see that the test instrumentation (or how it is called) is skipped. That may give a clue of the 'why'. There is a config file where sonar finds the sources. Have a look at configs of the plugins (unit and/or integration) of projects on the web.